# How to use predict_proba for DNNClassifier in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dotnetnuke

How to use `predict_proba` for `DNNClassifier` in tensorflow 1.5? I am using the code below. I believe, that the command to get the probability instead of the exact result class, may have changed as compared to previous tensorflow versions.

```
new_classifier = 
tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns, hidden_units=
[10, 20, 10],n_classes=int(trn_classes),model_dir=os.path.dirname("Model/"))
```

After that, when I use 
    `predictions =` 
list(new_classifier.predict_proba(input_fn=predict_input_fn))

I get error-

```
AttributeError: 'DNNClassifier' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your estimator is :

`new_classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns, hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],n_classes=int(trn_classes),model_dir=os.path.dirname("Model/"))`

for probabilities of each prediction try:

```
y_out_prob=new_classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn,predict_keys="probabilities")
```

i.e set **predict_keys='probalities'**